# The jqXHR object returned by the ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Either the success event or the error event will get the returned jqXHR object, but I can only access the jqXHR object in the error event.

```
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url:'https://fakeurl',
       data: formData,
       contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',                     
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(textStatus, jqXHR) {
           alert('textStatus: ' + textStatus + ' jqXHR.status: ' + jqXHR.status);
     },error: function(jqXHR) {
       console.log('jqXHR.status: ' + jqXHR.status);
     }
   });
```

The output in error event got jqXHR.status: 0.
And the output in success event is textStatus: [object Object] jqXHR.status: undefined.

Comment: `textStatus` would be `dataType:'json'`. That is your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the jQuery ajax [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> success
>
> Type: *Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )*
> ...

So, if you want to access the `jqXHR` object in the `success` callback, you'll need to define three parameters for the function to accept like so:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           alert('data: ' + data + 'textStatus: ' + textStatus + ' jqXHR.status: ' + jqXHR.status);
```

Comment: Then I just realized that I don't know how to implement function correctly.... Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get back the submitted data, the first argument of success function is the submitted data and the second is the textStatus, the third one for jqXHR which that has all the properties of the response object

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url:'https://fakeURL',
   data: formData,
   contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      alert('textStatus: ' + textStatus + ' jqXHR: ' + jqXHR.status);
 },error: function(error) {
   console.log('error.status: ' + error.status);
 }
});
```

Comment: This is wrong.  As it says in the ajax documentation:

*success*

_Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )_

A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: *The data returned from the server*, formatted according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.